# Git hooks to display a message everytime someone commits a .doc file

Tags: git, hook, githooks, git-commit, pre-commit-hook

I would like to know how to display a message using Git hooks every time they commit a Word document ( .doc/.docx) file , to let people know that they should rather commit .xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
#!/bin/sh

TMP="$PWD/.tmp"
git status --porcelain | grep '.doc' > "$TMP"

while read -r commitLine; do
    added=$(printf '%s\n' "$commitLine" | cut -c1)
    test "$added" = "A" && {
        commitLine=$(printf '%s\n' "$commitLine" | cut -d\  -f 3-)
        list=$(printf "${list}${commitLine}\n")
    }
done < "$TMP"
rm "$TMP"

test ! -z "$list" && {
    cat << EOF
Doc and Docx files currently staged:

${list}

Please remove them before commit.
EOF
    exit 1
}
```

Write it to an executable in .git/hooks/pre-commit

Comment: Unfortunatly I got this error when I did this:

`git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false commit -q -F   C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\bmm1r3ev.b2i   
cut: the delimiter must be a single character  
Try 'cut --help' for more information.  



.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 24: warning: here-document at line 16   delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')  


.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 25: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Completed with errors, see above.`

Comment: @Theologie I can't help it if your cygwin environment doesn't implement POSIX correctly.